# Prevent Flutter Provider from rebuilding widgets in previous screen due updates on current screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am still looking a better statement to fully express my problem here, so in detail here it is

Using `Provider` allows rebuilding widgets on changes which will affect them. Great!.

---

Suppose on the main screen(say `HomePage`) I toggle the theme between dark and light via a switch. The widgets are rebuilt on the main screen.
Now I navigate to some other screen(say `NextScreen`).

Here a button allows me to toggle the theme again. I toggle the theme then the widgets on the current screen(which is `NextScreen`) are rebuilt. But the Flutter Performance tab on Android Studio shows that the widgets on the previous screen(`HomePage`) are also redrawn.

---

So, my questions are

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a way to prevent rebuilding widgets which are not on the current screen and rebuild them only when we go back to the particular screen?

#### My code is a simple example of 90 lines

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeState>(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
        routes: {
          "next": (context) => NextScreen(),
        },
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ThemeState(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ThemeState>(builder: (BuildContext context, ThemeState value, Widget child) {
      return Theme(
        data: value.getTheme(),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              SwitchListTile(
                title: Text("Enable dark mode"),
                value: value.isDarkModeOn,
                onChanged: (_) => value.toggleTheme(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "next"),
            child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}

class NextScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ThemeState>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Theme(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Next Screen"),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => value.toggleTheme(),
                child: Text("Toggle theme"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          data: value.getTheme(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ThemeState with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDark = true;
  static ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark();
  static ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light();

  ThemeData _currentTheme = darkTheme;

  ThemeData getTheme() => _currentTheme;

  get isDarkModeOn => isDark;

  toggleTheme() {
    _currentTheme = isDark ? lightTheme : darkTheme;

    isDark = !isDark;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

---

[image: Here is the Performance tab screenshot]

Comment: Did u find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As the your consumer provider widget is the parent of other widgets, so when the provider is updating on toggle, consumer child widget will also update.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you are using Consumer and Theme widget unnecessarily, rebuilding too many widgets needlessly. I have refactored the code so that it is used only once for the app ThemeData, where Flutter will handle the further updates of the child widgets in an optimized way, which will inevitably need to be updated.

In the others, I removed the Consumers where they weren't necessary, ensuring they won't rebuild again the widgets when the theme changes. Additionally, I set listen to false on provider's instances in builds that didn't require Consumer. More details are in the code comments.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeState(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeState>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, ThemeState value, Widget? child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            home: const HomePage(),
            theme: value
                .getTheme(), // Set the initial theme and then listen for changes
            routes: {
              "next": (context) => const NextScreen(),
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Consumer(
            builder: (BuildContext context, ThemeState value, Widget? child) {
              // Consumer needed only for the SwitchListTile widget value
              // Rebuilds only the SwitchListTile widget when the value changes
              return SwitchListTile(
                title: const Text("Enable dark mode"),
                value: value.isDarkModeOn,
                onChanged: (_) {
                  value.toggleTheme();
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "next"),
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final value = Provider.of<ThemeState>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    ); // don't listen for changes, since listen is set to false
    // Don't need a Consumer widget here, since we are listening for changes on the main MaterialApp widget
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Next Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            value.toggleTheme();
          },
          child: const Text("Toggle theme"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThemeState with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDark = true;
  static final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark();
  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light();

  ThemeData _currentTheme = darkTheme;

  ThemeData getTheme() => _currentTheme;

  get isDarkModeOn => isDark;

  toggleTheme() {
    _currentTheme = isDark ? lightTheme : darkTheme;
    isDark = !isDark;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```